# Creating nested Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, hashmap

I'm trying to write data from a forum into a JSON file. The hierarchy in the JSON file is supposed to look something this:

```
thread_id
  post_id
      ...some_items...
```

Or more specifically:

```
{
    "0101": {
      "title": "Hi everybody",
      "1001": {...},
      "1002": {...}
    },
}
```

The relevant part in my function looks like this:

```
return {
  thread_id.to_i => {
    :title => title,
    post_id.to_i => {...}
  }
}
```

The result is that each post becomes the child of a new parent `thread_id`:

```
{  
   "0101":{  
      "title":"Hi everybody",
      "1001":{...}
   },
   "0101":{  
      "1002":{...}
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide more of your method? Clearly you wrap each post in a thread node, however to help you we'll need to know how you loop over your data.

Comment: `:title => title` or `"title":"Hi everybody"` doesn't fit anywhere in the JSON format that you claim to be making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the JSON schema you're trying to achieve is not quite right in my opinion. See what you think of this:

```
{
  "threads": [
    {
      "id": 100,
      "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      ...
      "posts": [
        {
          "id": 1000,
          "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
          ...
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

And the answer to your question depends on how your data is starting out, which we don't know, so I'll answer in terms of what I might expect the data structure to look like. (Note: don't use the constant `Thread`; it is already a Ruby class used for something totally unrelated.)

```
class ForumThread

  def self.serialize(threads)
    { threads: threads.map(&:serialize) }
  end

  def serialize
    attrs_to_serialize.inject({}) do |hash, attr|
      hash[attr] = send(attr)
      hash
    end
  end

  def serialized_posts
    posts.map &:serialize
  end

  def attrs_to_serialize
    [:id, :title, ..., :serialized_posts]
  end

end

class ForumPost

  def serialize
    attrs_to_serialize.inject({}) do |hash, attr|
      hash[attr] = send(attr)
      hash
    end
  end

  def attrs_to_serialize
    # same sort of thing as above
    # ...
  end

end

# Given the `threads` variable below holds an array or array-like
# object of ForumThread instances you could do this:

JSON.generate ForumThread.serialize(threads) # => { "threads": [...] }
```